# Can I fit a mixed effect model with only one explanatory variable?

Tags: lme4-nlme, model, meta-analysis, glmm

I am trying to understand how age (years) affects hormone concentration. Individual ID is included as a random intercept as this is a repeated measurement. I would like to use a mixed effect model. However, I am struggling to understand how I would find the significance of my explanatory variable as R will not let me fit a model with no explanatory variable. Something else I am struggling with is understanding which model is best to fit. For example, what is the difference between a mixed-effect model, linear mixed-effect model and glmm? I understand the distribution of my variables is important but if anyone can explain the key differences, that would be amazing. Thank you all, and I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Isn't your model of "how age (years) affects hormone concentration" something like `conc~age +(1|ID)`? That would make `age` your "explanatory variable." How many repeated measurements do you typically have per individual? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.